# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. What does '\\' mean?

Tags: python, path, directory-structure, joblib

[image: code]

I am getting the following error from my code:

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 650, in load with open(filename, 'rb') as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'artifacts\\model_trainer\\model.joblib'`

Here is the location of my model 'model.joblib':

`C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\Real_projects\End_to_end_ml_project_mlops\artifacts\model_trainer\model.joblib`

and the location of this file from where I am trying to access 'model.joblib':

`C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\Real_projects\End_to_end_ml_project_mlops\src\mlproject\pipeline\prediction.py`

I have tried passing the full address of the file this way:

`self.model = joblib.load(Path("C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\Real_projects\End_to_end_ml_project_mlops\artifacts\model_trainer\model.joblib"))`

I have tried doing this by using forward slashes (/) as well.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The last `joblib.load()` call in your question should have worked, assuming that full path is correct.

Comment: And yes, please do use forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Comment: The double \\ is just how python prints backslashes.  That is not the cause of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using backslashes again like this:

```
self.model = joblib.load('C:\\Users\\Dell\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Real_projects\\End_to_end_ml_project_mlops\\artifacts\\model_trainer\\model.joblib')
```

OR

Also since both these files are in the same directory you can also add "Relative Paths" like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

model_path = Path(__file__).parent / ".." / ".." / "artifacts" / "model_trainer" / "model.joblib"
self.model = joblib.load(model_path)
```

Let me know if it helps (;